# hide button action when status is completed

Tags: codeigniter

I am beginner of codeigniter

I want to hide this button action when status is completed.

**Check screenshot**

[image]

```
<div class="btn-wrapper pull-left">
     <a target="__blank" href="<?php echo $burl.'/print_delivery 
     id='.$value['order_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-success md-trigger">
          <i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print
     </a>
</div>
```

and this is my controller

```
public function print_delivery()
{
    $id_order = $this->input->get('id');

    $this->load->model('Order');
    $this->Order->updatePrintStatus($id_order);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Here in `$value['status']` status stands for `field name for your status field in your table`

```
<div class="btn-wrapper pull-left">
    <?php if($value['status']!='Completed'){?> 
    <a target="__blank" href="<?php echo $burl.'/print_delivery 
     id='.$value['order_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-success md-trigger">
          <i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print
     </a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: thats not workkk i got error

btw this is my status

$data['order_status'] = ['wc-processing'=>'Processing', 'wc-on-hold'=>'On Hold', 'wc-completed'=>'Completed', 'wc-pending'=>'Pending'];

Comment: I don't know the exact  field name for your status and the value for completed so change the code accordingly or show your table. `what error you are getting`

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: wc-completed

Filename: views/order.php

Line Number: 101

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\lab-new\application\views\order.php
Line: 101
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\lab-new\application\controllers\Admin.php
Line: 151
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\lab-new\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: @YadhuBabu's answer should works, the only thing you have to do is inside if logic. I think it would be same as you show the status in `Order Status` field.